# Laravel использование this->field в relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

У меня есть таблица havings, rigs и parts.
В таблице havings есть поле part_id, по которому можно получить доступ к part, которая привязана к havings.
В таблице rigs всё немного сложнее - несколько полей: GPU_id, RAM_id ...

Итак, в модели Having определено отношение hasOne для модели Part. Как определить отношение в модели Having для модели Rig?

```js
 public function rig() {
    return $this->hasOne(Rig::class, $this->part->type . '_id', 'id');
}
```

Я пробовал так, но это работает почему-то только для GPU_id, если type = RAM, то rig = null.
А если вывести `dump($this->part->type)`, то выводится 1 строка - `GPU`

Вот мои таблицы (между having и part есть таблица part_shop, но это роли не играет в этом вопросе)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как связаны part и rig по каким полям?

Comment: part->having<-rig. Ну то есть через having - `$this->belongsTo(Having::class, $localKey)->with(['part'])`

Comment: В таблице having есть поле rig_id по которому она связана с rig ? или каким образом? Сделайте скрин таблиц... а то сложно ответить

Comment: Окей, добавил. Наоборот - в таблице rigs есть несколько полей, в которых записаны having_id: GPU_id, platform_id и тд